# OracleUdt throwing AgrumentException in .NET Application

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net, odp.net-unmanaged

We are getting following exception while using oracle UDT:

ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:....

> at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetAllReferencedAssemblies()
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.RegAndConfigRdr.setudtmapping(Hashtable& s_mapUdtNameToMappingObj)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetCustomTypeMappings()
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetUdtName(String customTypeName, String dataSource)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.SetUDTFromCustomObject(OracleConnection conn, IOracleCustomType customObj, Int32 i)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_Collection(OracleConnection conn)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize, Boolean bIsFromEF, Boolean bIsSelectStmt)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
> at DBConn.DB_Command.ExecuteReader()

Happens only on the production machine. Not reproducible in local developer environment.
Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: of course, you cut down the part of error that tells you what is wrong. You having a duplicate data. Nothing **we** can do about it

Comment: This is the only exception that i have got. We cut nothing

Comment: again, read the message. your program attempting to add the key, which already exists  here `Hashtable.Insert`. Which basically can mean that in your production data you have some dups

Comment: I'm so sorry. Did you read the exception? Did you see who call HashTable.Insert? The only thing my program does - call to common ExecuteReader().

Comment: I am very grateful that you are trying to help me, but unfortunately you are wrong. This is how oracle does the mapping between UDTs and their C # representation; the code works fine with any type of application except Web.API. Solution we temporarily found by putting udt mapping in Web.config. Thanks